# Programmatically Generating Namespaces for CLI application

Tags: php

I am creating a little CLI tool to assist in using a PHP library I built. One of the requirements of this tool is to Generate custom classes and interfaces, from a STUB template, all from a CLI command.

However, I am having a bit of problems with generating namespaces correctly.

So, I have this one stub file that looks like this.

```
<?php

namespace DummyNamspace;

use Spheracle\ApplicationService\ApplicationServiceInterface;

interface DummyContextNameServiceInterface extends ApplicationServiceInterface
{
    // your code goes here
}

?>
```

I am using [this library](https://github.com/constant-null/backstubber) to create the stubs.

And, in my command class (Symfony), I have this code to create the namespace, which is passed to the generator directly.

```
$ns = ($project) ? $project . "\\" . $context : $context;
$generator = new AppServiceInterfaceGenerator($context, $dir, $ns);
$generator->generate();
```

here, $ms is the namespace text that will be placed in the STUB file. However, when I run this code via its assigned CLI command, I get the following output in the generated file.

My expected namespace for this entry is `Foo\Bar'. However, I get the following.

```
<?php

namespace 'Bar'Namspace;

use Spheracle\ApplicationService\ApplicationServiceInterface;

interface 'Bar'ContextNameServiceInterface extends ApplicationServiceInterface
{
    // your code goes here
}

?>
```

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong? I assume the issue with the interface name would be resolved once the namespace issue is resolved. I have a feeling the problem might have something to do with the underlying library I am using to generate the classes. But, I want to get other's option to double check my work before I start searching for a better stub generation library.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you check the content of `$context` - especially check if it has the quotes in the value.

Comment: @Nigel Ren I tried running str_replace(”’”, ””, $ns) and str_replace(’”’, ’”’, $ns) on $ns to make sure quotes were removed. Unfortunately, I am still getting the same incorrect output.

Comment: Not sure, but can you also try this with `$project`.

Comment: Just did. Issue still persists.

Comment: I guess I may have to repost this tomorrow. Lol